# Subquery left join not returning what expected

Tags: mysql

A row in the bids table looks something like this:

```
        [id] => 108
        [item_id] => 467
        [user_id] => 66
        [bid] => 24
        [bid_date] => 2015-03-19 10:17:12
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the items from the `items` table (which is happening) but also get the highest bid and count the bids which are in the `bids` table. Right now, the below query is only returning the max bid and counting bids for one item. How do I change it to return the two for each item?

```
"SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.item_title, t1.item_number, t1.item_start, t1.item_description, t1.active, t2.first_name, t2.last_name, t2.fb_id, b.maxbid, b.bids
            FROM
              items t1
            LEFT JOIN
              users t2
            ON
              t1.user_id = t2.id
            LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT item_id, MAX(bid) AS maxbid, COUNT(bid) AS bids
              FROM bids
            ) b
            ON t1.id = b.item_id
            WHERE t1.active = 1
            ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: You are linking user_id with item table instead of bid. Also you can left outer join item and bid table in case there are no bids. This is a hunch ... If this isn't it, show us the tables and an example of the result you expect.

Comment: There are three tables. Items, users and bids. I want all items, but I also need the user's name, that's why I joined the users table. And I expect to get the highest bid and the number of bids for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a

```
group by item_id
```

In your subquery b